# Why is Clang confused by @try{} in a block with no return statement?

Tags: objective-c, clang, objective-c-blocks

Under normal conditions, when a block is declared to return a value, but no `return` statement actually appears in the block, Clang fails to compile it with an error (of a missing return value).

However, this breaks when that block contains `@try{} @catch(...){}` or `@try{} @finally{}`.

Does anyone know why?

The way I found this was when using `@weakify()` and `@strongify()` in `RACExtScope` in ReactiveCocoa, in one block I forgot to return a signal. But the compiler didn't warn me and crashed on runtime, which lead me to dig into it, preprocess the code and find that this causes it. Any explanation would be very much appreciated, I honestly don't know why this would happen, thanks!

I also created a gist, in case someone had a comment/suggestion: https://gist.github.com/czechboy0/11358741

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    id (^iReturnStuff)() = ^id() {
        @try{} @finally{}
        //if you comment out line 4, Clang will not compile this.
        //if you leave it like this, Clang will compile and run this, even though
        //there's no value being returned.
        //is there something special in @try{} that turns off compiler errors?
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: looks like clang bug to me. C++ `try{}catch(...){}` will not make it compile in [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e572df2bc1a80cef)

Comment: well in my test when I call the block it "Happens" to return nil... but it is UB... it looks like a bug to me, there should be the same warning/error (depending on settings) as a function that is supposed to return something, but doesn't...

Comment: It might do this since `@try` implies an exception might be expected, and an exception would exit the block without it returning, so it doesn't complain about no return value. I would still say this is a bug if that is what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Clang's block specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html) makes brief mention of control flow in a block.  I've reproduced it here (emphasis mine)

> The compound statement of a Block is treated much like a function body
>   with respect to control flow in that goto, break, and continue do not
>   escape the Block. **Exceptions are treated normally in that when thrown
>   they pop stack frames until a catch clause is found.**

Reading through a little further, you really get the sense that exceptions in Objective-C are downright *weird*.  From [the section on exceptions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions)

> The standard Cocoa convention is that exceptions signal programmer
>   error and are not intended to be recovered from. Making code
>   exceptions-safe by default would impose severe runtime and code size
>   penalties on code that typically does not actually care about
>   exceptions safety. Therefore, ARC-generated code leaks by default on
>   exceptions, which is just fine if the process is going to be
>   immediately terminated anyway. Programs which do care about recovering
>   from exceptions should enable the option.

From the above, one could reasonably deduce that the ObjC exceptions specification is so fragile or malleable that not even the compiler writers can guarantee stable code against it, therefore they just disabled all reasonable termination checks in once @try-@catch are encountered.

This can also be seen in the code generated by Clang with and without the try-catches.  First, without

```
___main_block_invoke:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movabsq $0, %rax
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rdi, -16(%rbp)
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

This is pretty simple x86 that pushes a new stack frame, moves 0 (nil) into the return register, then returns.  Now, with the try-catch block:

```
___main_block_invoke:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $64, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
    movb    $0, -25(%rbp)
    movl    -32(%rbp), %eax
    testb   $1, -25(%rbp)
    movl    %eax, -48(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    jne LBB1_1
    jmp LBB1_3
    LBB1_1:
    callq   _objc_exception_rethrow
    jmp LBB1_2
    LBB1_2:
    LBB1_3:
    movl    -48(%rbp), %eax         ## 4-byte Reload
    movl    %eax, -32(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdi
    addq    $64, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    jmp _objc_autoreleaseReturnValue ## TAILCALL
    LBB1_4:
    movl    %edx, %ecx
    movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
    movl    %ecx, -44(%rbp)
    testb   $1, -25(%rbp)
    jne LBB1_5
    jmp LBB1_7
    LBB1_5:
    callq   _objc_end_catch
    jmp LBB1_6
    LBB1_6:
    jmp LBB1_7
    LBB1_7:
    jmp LBB1_8
    LBB1_8:
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __Unwind_Resume
    LBB1_9:
    movq    %rdx, -56(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    movq    %rax, -64(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    callq   _objc_terminate
```

Besides the more complicated function proem, notice the lack of a proper `ret`.  The function still has two exit points,

```
jmp   _objc_autoreleaseReturnValue
```

and

```
call  _objc_terminate
```

The first is a relatively new feature of the language where, when in the tailcall position, it can be used to omit `-autoreleases` in favor of drawing upon thread-local variables by examining the code that came before it.  The second begins immediate termination of the process and jumps into the C++ exception handling mechanism.  What this means is that the function does, in fact, have the requisite exit points to keep CLANG from complaining about missing return statements.  Unfortunately, what it also means is that CLANG's forgoing of messing with the ObjC exception mechanism can potentially message garbage, as you've seen.  This is one of the reasons EXTScope has [switched to using the `@autoreleasepool` directive](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/commit/ce2c3550c47cbd444f41de9419ccb1fa9546afe1) to eat that sigil.

Comment: Thank you very much for this exhaustive answer, I really appreciate it. I figured it would be something like this (still, thanks for taking the time to copy over the assembly of the resulting block). So would you agree it is a bug in Clang? Because that is basically what I'm asking - whether someone can explain to me why this is happening (which you did and I appreciate it) and what to do about it. I really discovered this by accident (and I know a lot of frameworks are using autorelease instead in macros), but I'd still like to hear from someone whether this is a bug or desired behavior.

Comment: I cannot speak as a CLANG developer, but I can give my opinion, and that is that this was accidental, but not a bug.  Just a collision of standards and implementation that happens to produce undesired behavior.  Still, it wouldn't hurt to open a ticket somewhere to let the CLANG guys know about this.

Comment: I actually emailed them but I haven't heard back yet. And thanks again for the explanation. Since I was looking for someone to confirm whether this is a bug, I'll still leave the bounty on to try to bring more attention to the question, but if nobody from the Clang team answers here, I'll mark your question as accepted before the bounty ends.

Comment: Sounds good.  I've opened [something on Clang's Bugzilla](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19641) for this one too.

Comment: I haven't heard back from the Clang guys - have you?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in clang, this one: https://llvm.org/PR46693. It also happens without blocks -- `@try` just confuses clang.

Trunk clang will flag your example if you replace the `@finally` with a `@catch`:

```
% cat foo.mm
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    id (^iReturnStuff)() = ^id() {
        @try{} @catch(id i){}
    };
}

% out/gn/bin/clang -c foo.mm
foo.mm:5:5: error: non-void block does not return a value
    };
    ^
```

Hopefully it'll be fixed for `@finally` eventually too.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725644/obj-c-method-without-return-statement-compiles-if-it-includes-a-try-catch-bloc/69670393#comment123149684_69670393).