# Obj-C method without return statement compiles if it includes a @try @catch block

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, return, try-catch, warnings

Question:  How do I get Xcode to report the missing return?

Below is a new Xcode 11 test-app. I added the `shouldReturnAnObject` method with an empty @try/@catch block and **no return value**. This compiles and analyzes without warnings or errors.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (nonnull id)shouldReturnAnObject {
    @try {
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
    } @finally {
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    id obj = [self shouldReturnAnObject];
    NSLog(@"obj: %@", obj);
}
@end
```

If I remove the @try block from it fails to compile with the error: `Control reaches end of non-void function`. This is the behavior I expect for any method with no return return.

Versions:Xcode 11.5, macOS 10.15.5. No build settings changed.
Adding `-Wall` doesn't change the behavior.

**I understand Cocoa best practice is to use exceptions only as exceptional. The real app uses exception rarely, and only to guard against truly exceptional behavior. I'm providing a simple test-app to focus on the issue.**

I believe this behavior has existed in Xcode/Clang for a long time. If the behavior is intentional can someone explain why this behavior exists?whi

Related info: I have also built quick test apps in:

- C++ (Clang++) : compile fails with the error `-Wreturn-type`
- Java () : compile fails with `error: missing return statement`
- Objective-C++ (using a .mm file): no warnings, no errors, compile succeeds

Comment: Strange - even if you wrap that ```try ... catch``` into some arbitrary ```if``` it still does not give the error. Even if you nest it into two ```if```'s it still does not.

Comment: @skaak That is really strange, especially since it works with `if (false)` which the compiler usually understands is never executed. Something about the try/catch causes it to just "give up" on the flow analysis.

Comment: Thanks to @jtbandes for filing this in the Clang project here: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46693  –  there is also some new progress on this noted in the bug as of Oct '21 here: https://reviews.llvm.org/D112287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. There's an LLVM bug for this filed at https://llvm.org/PR46693

Comment: We’ve come full circle! I filed this bug last year as a result of this question; see the comment thread on my answer above.  Thanks for working on the fix!

Comment: @jtbandes - thanks for the mention in the bug.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

To me, this definitely appears to be a compiler bug. (You can file a bug at https://bugs.llvm.org/) Evidence follows.

I tried the following things and the problem persists:

- `@try {} @catch (NSException *e) {}` with no `@finally`
- `@try {} @finally {}` with no `@catch`
- `+` instead of `-`
- Address Sanitizer
- Undefined Behavior Sanitizer
- `-Weverything`

Despite the compiler's refusal to generate a warning, you can see using LLDB that it generates an effectively completely empty method body (with optimization enabled):

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100000eb4 asdf`-[MyObj shouldReturnAnObject](self=0x0000000103108440, _cmd="shouldReturnAnObject") at main.m:23:1 [opt]
    frame #1: 0x0000000100000eee asdf`main(argc=<unavailable>, argv=<unavailable>) at main.m:31:79 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x00007fff684f6cc9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #3: 0x00007fff684f6cc9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb) disassemble
asdf`-[MyObj shouldReturnAnObject]:
    0x100000eb0 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x100000eb1 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
->  0x100000eb4 <+4>: popq   %rbp
    0x100000eb5 <+5>: retq   
    0x100000eb6 <+6>: nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ZkF48u shows the same, although the program fails to link because there's no Obj-C runtime available there. And you can try different compiler versions — indeed, the problem seems to have existed at least since Clang 3.0.0.

[image]

Finally, with some luck/care you can observe that the lack of return value results in undefined behavior. Here, in lieu of the missing return value, the program just grabs whatever happened to be on the stack already, such as a string:

[image]

Comment: Definitely a bug. I've tried getting the compiler to complain / pick up the issue in various ways - putting the ```try``` inside an if or for but nothing works. I was hoping to put some barrier between the try and the message definition where I *think* the bug originates. If, however, I put that try in some kind of a block inside the function then it starts complaining about the return value.

Comment: Bassed on this - where if you hide it away in a block, I suppose a message with a try catch gets handled differently to a 'normal' message without one and in that difference lies the bug.

Comment: Anyhow - scary what you do with the stack, but cool too. You just turned Objective-C into a huge RPN calculator. Think of all the new possibilities this opens up. You can write some of the most unreadable but still working code known to man this way.

Comment: Sorry for all the clutter - problem is definitely a message with try. Take any of your more complex messages and remove the return statement. Immediately this lights up in Xcode with the 'non-void message no return value' error. Then add a @try anywhere to the message and it disappears.

Comment: I think if I’m being as accurate as possible, it’s not actually the stack but the `eax` register.

Comment: Unfortunately the llvm group isn't accepting new members -- or they're screening them. I applied last week, but have not received a response yet. If you (or anyone else) wants to file it, I'd appreciate it. -- I did file with Apple: FB7851551

Comment: I already had an account, so I filed https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46693

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up notes:

Credit for finding the case in clang goes to @jtbandes.
It looks like this case is just unimplemented.
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/lib/Analysis/CFG.cpp#L3666

He also tracked down the original "FIXME" commit 11 years ago.
https://twitter.com/jtbandes/status/1279870326784929792

I've submitted ~radar~ Feedback Assistant bug to Apple:FB7851551

I don't have an llvm contributor account and they're not taking new members due to spam, so can't submit a bug there. If someone else wants to, that would be awesome. And if they do grant me an account I'll follow up with the bug report there too.

And with that, I think it's case closed. Maybe with a little luck this can make it into final releases of SDKs this fall.    Thanks everyone for helping me find this one.